# Forcing labels to fit inside polygons

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to fit labels inside polygons, but when I export the map, because of the small size of some polygons, the labels don't fit or they overlap.

Is it possible to automate the size of the labels based on the size of the polygons or other way to put the labels in a proper way?

[image]

Comment: If you can find a way to manually label some of the thinnest & densest polygons so that they are fine at your layout scale you might show us what that would look like.  My initial reaction for an auto solution is to change your placement settings mode to free to allow labels to rotate to fit in a polygon, but you might not want that.  You could create a label font size field, roughly use area to fill it and then use the data defined override cabinet to apply those.  Callouts might be another option. https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-add-leader-lines-to-labels-in-qgis-3-10/

Comment: Thank you for your answer John, I've decided to place the label with the Free angle from the placement options and works good.